# How to find $\theta$ bounds when calculating the volume enclosed between sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4a^2$ and cylinder $x^2+(y-a)^2=a^2$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, volume

> I need to find $\theta$ bounds when calculating the volume enclosed between sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4a^2$ and cylinder $x^2+(y-a)^2=a^2$. The final answer must be that volume=$\frac{48\pi-64}{9}$.

Here's an illustration:

[image]

Let $$V=\int\int\int_Bf(\theta,r,z)dV$$

Because of the symmetry of volume relative of the $y$ axis we can calculate the volume of the upper half then multiply it by 2.

Then:
$$
0\le z\le \sqrt{4a^2-x^2-y^2} \le \sqrt{4a^2-r^2}
$$

Because our the given surfaces don't have their center at the origin we need to adjust the $r$. We can retrieve it from the cylinder equation, $r=2a\sin\theta$. So:
$$
0\le r\le 2a\sin\theta
$$
Finally, the projection of the surface onto the $xy$ plane is a circle. So I think that $0\le \theta \le 2\pi$.

**But** I don't get the correct answer with this angle range.

If we evaluate the triple integral we'll get to this expression in the end:
$$
E=-\frac{8a^3}{3}(\frac{1}{3}\cos^2\theta \sin\theta+\frac{2}{3}\sin\theta-\theta)
$$

For example:
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}E=\frac{16\pi}{3}a^3
$$
which is not the answer I should've got.

However if I choose the following bounds for $\theta$:
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}E=\frac{12\pi-16}{9}a^3
$$
The last bounds give the volume of the quarter of the original volume so if we multiply it by $4$ we get the desired answer:
$$
\frac{12\pi-16}{9}a^3\cdot 4=\frac{48\pi-64}{9}
$$

Please explain why my bounds are not good.

Comment: The projection of cylinder on the xy plane lies above the $x$ axis.  $0\le\theta\le\pi$ traces out the entire region.

Comment: Aren't we interested what is the shape of the projection onto $xy$ plane, which is a circle? What does $\theta$ give us?

Comment: $r = 2a\sin\theta$ is a circle in polar coordinates.  We only need to look at the values of $\theta$ where $r\ge 0$ before we start to trace out that circle for a second time.

Comment: I have one more wrinkle for you. $(\cos^2 \theta)^{\frac 32} = |\cos^3 \theta|$

Comment: @DougM so we need to adjust the angle not to get negative values in $r$ this is the logic for the range $0\le \theta \le \pi$? If for example it was that $0 \le r \le 5$ then it'd be correct to make the angle range $0 \le \theta \le 2\pi$?

Comment: I suggest you draw it out on a sheet of paper, plot each point of $r = 2\sin\theta$ for multiple values of $\theta$, and look at what is happening.  That should improve your intuition for these sorts of problems.

Comment: I did, I plotted the function and its values are negative between $\pi$ and and $2\pi$. So I think I understand, because it's a function we need to be careful that we function doesn't "break away" from the intended region. While when $r$ is bounded by constants we're guaranteed that the radius length can only vary between 2 constants

Comment: @DougM Regarding the $|\cos^3\theta|$ I assume it's the same issue that between $0$ and $\pi$ we can get negative values. But then I guess I should use these bounds $0\le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ and then multiply the result by 4 right?

Comment: In my mind it is actually a little bit different.  It is more about elementary algebra  $(x^2)^\frac 32 = |x^3|$  If x were negative, squaring it would make it positive.  Then exponentiating that would keep it positive.

Comment: @DougM Yes you're right, I meant that if I don't change the bounds and remain with $0\le \theta \le \pi$ I would have to make 2 separate calculations to account for negative and positive values of $\cos$. But if I restrict the bounds to a region where $\cos$ is always positive then I need to do only one calculation. Of course I understand that still it's $|\cos^3\theta|$ but in the new range $|\cos^3\theta|=\cos^3\theta$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 2 is incorrect because both limits vanish $E$  at $0, 2\pi$ . Steps 3 and 4 are correct evaluating between limits $ \int _{\pi/2}^0 $ and multiplying by $4.$

Comment: btw intersection  is called Viviani curve