A volume problem in multivariable calculus that gives us $2$ different answers on $2$ different occasions.
Find the volume of the solid contained inside the cylinder $x^2+(y-a)^2=a^2$ and the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=4a^2.$
Now, I was able to solve this problem by evaluating $V=\int\int_D\int_0^{4a^2-x^2-y^2}dzdA$ where $D$ is the disk of radius $a$ centered at $(0,a).$
Thus, the required volume is $4\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^{2a\sin \theta}r\sqrt{4a^2-r^2}drd\theta.$
However, if I take the limits differently, i.e $2\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2a\sin \theta}r\sqrt{4a^2-r^2}drd\theta,$ I should have got the same answer since, the region remains the same.

More precisely, $\int_0^{2a\sin\theta}r\sqrt{4a^2-r^2}dr=1-\cos^3\theta.$
So, my problem is that $2\int_0^{\pi}1-\cos^3\theta d\theta\neq 4\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}1-\cos^3\theta d\theta.$ This is precisely why the above two integrals are not equal.

Surprisingly, the answer matches in the former case but not in the later. I have no clue about the reason for this anomaly.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2305889/how-to-find-theta-bounds-when-calculating-the-volume-enclosed-between-sphere

@RobertZ Please see my edited post.

It should be $\sqrt{4a^2-r^2}$ in both cases. The two integrals are equal.

@RobertZ Fixed it. But no, the integrals aren't equal. The second integral os $\pi$ and the former one is not so. I checked it on Wolfram alpha

Well, it means that your computations on Wolfram alpha are wrong... ;-)

@RobertZ  That's not the case at all. How are you so sure about that? :P

The integrals are equal because $\sin\theta$ is symmetric about $\frac\pi2$. What inputs did you use? Did you try evaluating the integrals by hand?

@user170231 Yes, I did. I explained the problem more precisely and did a calculation in the original post.

$\int r\sqrt{4a^2-r^2}dr=-1/3 (4 a^2 - r^2)^{3/2}$, so putting $r=2a\sin(\theta)$ we find something with $(\cos^2(\theta))^{3/2}$ which is $|\cos(\theta)|^3$  (with modulus!)

Thanks for updating the post, Thomas. Similar problem, with the same hurdle, solved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4924558/
